# Internet explorer 8 blue colored textboxes in my PC

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-8

I use Firefox in daily use. While testing own web-application in Internet Explorer, I've get bug like this(as example facebook.com page):

[image]

As example I capture facebook.com website. Blue colored textboxes. This issue then I catch in other web-sites.

How to fix this problem? I haven't installed any plugin to IE and haven't customized it ever.
Is anybody catch same problem?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, customize your color scheme in Windows? IE takes its UI colors from there...

Comment: It's something on your computer.  The textboxes are all white on mine.

Comment: I haven't customize. I don't love customizing Windows:) 
Why "FirsName", "LastName", "YourEmail" fields not normal, but New Passwork shown nowmally? behavior is not predictable

Comment: Looks like some kind of auto form-filler is indicating it could auto-fill. You got one of those?

Comment: @Piskovr: just now in Control Panel\Personalization I change to Classic Theme. problem not fixed.

Comment: I also reset IE, and + restore default setting. Bug not fixed.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks, good idea. I checked for auto form-filler. And found software named Asus Security Project Manager. So I turned off this app. all works as in other peoples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some kind of autocomplete turned on that highlights the fields. Perhaps you didn't intentionally install any kind of package, but it managed to sneak into your computer in some other way.

If you can't get rid of the autocomplete application, then just pretend that the form fields are not blue: it doesn't show up like that for anyone else.